# How to implement subdomain in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-router, vuejs3, router

I have a website where I can host different shop profiles and currently I'm generating the route with the help of shop name's slug, but instead of `https://example.com/shop/abc-shop` I wanted the route to be `https://abc-shop.example.com/` and upon looking up on the internet I can't find a way to do it with Vue3 router. Please suggest some approaches.

Comment: I guess you actually have a separate thing in the sub-domain. In that case, you can just use a regular link

Comment: I have the shop profile in subdomain, that's just a normal page for the shop. How can I seperate that so that I get routed to the subdomain by default?

Comment: It's unclear how you expect it to work. A different domain cannot be a part of SPA and so how it's related to Vue router. There has to be a redirect. You can do this with `location`.

Comment: Now, I have a shop profile which can be viewed at `https://example.com/shop/abc-shop` but I want to view that on `https://abc-shop.example.com/`

Comment: I mean how you expect it to work from tech point of view. It's a different site. It's the same as if you would like to make one of pages to be google.com. Redirect to it with window.location. It's not a part of the router.

Comment: Okay, so it can't be routed through router but that location could be changed with `window.location` as that's a different website?

Answer (score 2):

Old, but I do something like this with a similar need. (blogs)

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    let subdomain = window.location.host.split('.')[0]
    console.log(subdomain)
    if (subdomain != 'www' && subdomain != 'localhost:3000') {
        to.params['subdomain']= subdomain
    }
    next()
})
```

then you can handle it in your template , for me I use a custom component called blogRouterView that contains specific paths and then parses this.$route to know what component to include using async components. (`<component :is="currentURLComponent"></component>`)

Answer (score 0):

Like Estus Flask wrote in comments subdomain is a completly diferent server. Browser treat it like it is separate www page. You need to write for this subdomain another vue project and in root domain redirect to this subdomain. Or you can prepere sub domain to be able to use in for example `<iframe>` tag.